# Dirichlet's theorem on prime density

Tags: analytic-number-theory, nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Does anyone knows where I could find the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on the analytic density of primes congruent to a certain integer $m$, which turns out to be $\frac{1}{\varphi(m)}$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Book by Harold Davenport "Multiplicative number theory" has a very nice exposition.

Comment: I voted to close this question. This is a very wellknown result and contained in plenty of textbooks and lecture notes on the subject.
To just find some proof of it seems easy enough. 

Comment: A proof that the density of primes congruent to $m$ (modulo some $N$ presumably) is $1/\phi(m)$ is unlikely to be found anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Serre's "Course in arithmetic" starts pretty low, and ends with that result. It is quite short too.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Introduction to analytic number theory' by T.Apostol (Chapter 7)

Or the Selberg article "An elementary proof of Dirichlet's theorem about primes in an arithmetic progression"

There is also several course note available on the web, just search for "Introduction to analytic number theory" or "Dirichlet's theorem" on google...